# Implement NSTextfield with labels

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstextfield

I am trying to implement a NSTextField that displays an autocomplete list and when an option is selected, the value is highlighted as an individual label.  The best way to describe this is how mail completes email addresses and separates each one with a background colour.

What is the best way to implement something like this, is a NSTextField the correct object or should I be using something else?  Are each of the values attributed strings?

[image: Text field with labels]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is already there. Use [NSTokenField](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTokenField_Class/Reference/Reference.html)